# Multiply numbers from two iterators in order and without duplicates

Tags: rust, iterator, multiplication

I have this code and I want every combination to be multiplied:

```rust
fn main() {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 9;

  for i in (min..=max).rev() {
      for j in (min..=max).rev() {
          println!("{}", i * j);
      }
  }
}
```

Result is something like:

```
81
72
[...]
9
72
65
[...]
8
6
4
2
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Is there a clever way to produce the results in descending order (without collecting and sorting) and without duplicates?

Comment: I don't think so. If you look at a multiplication table draw a line that goes through all the multiples of 9 in descending order without duplicates, it looks very erratic, I struggle to find a pattern in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this answer provides a solution for this specific problem (multiplication table) but the title asks a more general question (any two iterators).

The naive solution of storing all elements in a vector and then sorting it uses `O(n^2 log n)` time and `O(n^2)` space (where `n` is the size of the multiplication table).
You can use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) to reduce the memory to `O(n)`:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
fn main() {
    let n = 9;
    let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();
    for j in 1..=n {
        heap.push((9 * j, j));
    }
    let mut last = n * n + 1;
    while let Some((val, j)) = heap.pop() {
        if val < last {
            println!("{val}");
            last = val;
        }
        if val > j {
            heap.push((val - j, j));
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46182f1f09872a1c0e326afa4858a508).
The conceptual idea behind the algorithm is to consider 9 separate sequences

- `9*9, 9*8, 9*7, .., 9*1`
- `8*9, 8*8, 8*7, .., 8*1`
- ...
- `1*9, 1*8, 1*7, .., 1*1`

Since they are all decreasing, at a given moment, we only need to consider one element of each sequence (the largest one we haven't reached yet).
These are inserted into the priority queue which allows us to efficiently find the maximum one.
Once we have printed a given element we move onto the next one in the sequence and insert that into the priority queue.
By keeping track of the last element printed we can avoid duplicates.

Comment: Woah! Thanks so much for teaching me this concept, that's a really interesting approach. That's totally sufficient for me, even if the context of the question was a bit broader. I accept this as the answer as it totally shows the way to go